# Greedy sequences without k-term arithmetic progressions

Tags: additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression, infinite-sequences

If $S_k$ is the greedy sequence with no length-k arithmetic subsequence, (ie $S_3$ = [A003278](http://oeis.org/A003278) , $S_4$ = [A005837](http://oeis.org/A005837) , $S_5$ = [A020655](http://oeis.org/A020655) ), is it guaranteed that any other sequence $a$ with no length-k arithmetic subsequence has only terms which are $\ge$ those from $S_k$?

In other words, is it true that $\forall n, {S_k}_n \le a_n$ ?  If not, can someone give a counterexample?

Also, which of these sequences are known to be [small sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_set_%28combinatorics%29)?

Comment: Already for $k=3$ this must fail eventually, because the $n$-th term
grows roughly as $n^{\log_2 3}$ (e.g. the $2^k$-th term is
$(3^k+1)/2$), but it's known that for large $n$ there are
3AP-avoiding sets of size $n$ in 
$\lbrace 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n^{1+\epsilon} \rbrace$.
$$ $$
P.S. I see that a variation of this was asked here in 2011
but not answered: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80085

Comment: Could you give an example of such a set?

Comment: Behrend's construction for $n^{1+\epsilon}$ is explicit but somewhat
complicated, and probably takes some time to improve on A003278.
However, the big jump from $14$ to $28$ between terms $8$ and $9$
in the greedy sequence suggests that this is a good place to look,
and indeed it turns out that the narrowest AP3-free set of size $9$ is
$\lbrace 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 14, 15, 18, 20 \rbrace$ (unique up to reflection,
by an exhaustive search that took much longer to program in C and debug
than the fraction of a second it took to run).

Comment: (O.O.)P.S. I would have saved some time by first finding https://oeis.org/A065825 ...

Comment: ... or even trying the $n=5$ jump first!
($\lbrace 1, 2, 4, 8, 9 \rbrace$, $\lbrace 1, 3, 4, 8, 9 \rbrace$)

Comment: Thanks,
So does this imply that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions could potentially be undecidable or equivalent to AC or something like that?